# Error loading interstitial

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, admob, ads

I am trying to integrate a windows phone 8 app game with AdMob but am having some difficultly (I am using the latest ad mob widows sdk  - 6.5.11).

I can load and display AdMob Banners no problem, but get errors when I try to load an interstitial advert.

Basically, when the ad is loaded I get the following exceptions:

An exception of type 'System.SystemException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
An exception of type 'System.SystemException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
Failed to receive int ad with error NoFill

SO when I try to show the add I obviously get further exceptions:

An exception of type 'System.SystemException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
GoogleAds.InterstitialAd
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\en-US\mscorlib.debug.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in GoogleAds.DLL

Here is my code for loading:

```
 public static void LoadAdverts()
        {
            runInUIThread(
                () =>
                {
                    LoadGoogleInterstitialAd();    
                });
        }


        private static void LoadGoogleInterstitialAd()
        {
            // Initialize the ad
            mGoogleInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(mGoogleInterstitialAdUnitID);

            // Attach the interstitial event handlers.
            mGoogleInterstitialAd.ReceivedAd += OnGoogleInterstitialAdReceived;
            mGoogleInterstitialAd.FailedToReceiveAd += OnFailedToReceiveGoogleInterstitialAd;
            mGoogleInterstitialAd.DismissingOverlay += OnDismissingGoogleOverlay;

            AdRequest mGoogleInterstitialAdRequest = new AdRequest();
            mGoogleInterstitialAdRequest.ForceTesting = true;

            mGoogleInterstitialAd.LoadAd(mGoogleInterstitialAdRequest);
        }
```

The LoadAd() method is the one that generates the initial System exceptions.

Then to show the ad:

```
 public static void DisplayOverlayAdvert()
        {
            // Check that the overlay ad is not already displayed.
            if (!mIsGoogleInterstitialAdActive)
            {
                runInUIThread(
                    () =>
                    {
                        DisplayGoogleInterstitialAd();
                    });
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method displays an advert in the advert container grid.
        /// </summary>
        private static void DisplayGoogleInterstitialAd()
        {
            mGoogleInterstitialAd.ShowAd();

            // Set the flag to true as the ad is displayed.
            mIsGoogleInterstitialAdActive = true;
        }
```

ANy help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would hazard a guess that `DisplayGoogleInterstitialAd` is being called before `LoadGoogleInterstitialAd`.

Comment: I can with certainty confirm that load is called before display - and I have even tried putting the load functionality into the display method - still get the same error. Is there perhaps a problem with the admob windows phone sdk?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. Haven't coded for a Windows phone in the last seven years.